Google Sign-in in Razor Pages (.Net 7) cannot log me in
I have built a relatively simple website which is using ASP.NET Core Web App, Razor Page with .NET version 7. I'm just using my own authentication system (no Identity service). I was adding Google Authentication to the project using this guide.
Problem
When I click my button to sign-in with Google, I get a popup asking me to login (so far, so good).

But when I click "Next" on that popup, it says it cannot log me in.

I am having different problems with different browsers but I'm trying to get it working with one (Chrome) first, then I will sort out the others.
Code involved
Program.cs for Content Security Policy, and Cross Origin Opener Policy
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "script-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client;" +
        " frame-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;" +
        " connect-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin-allow-popups");
    await next();
});

appsettings.json
"Authentication": {
  "Google": {
    "ClientId": "<CLIENT-ID>",
    "ClientSecret": "<CLIENT-SECRET>"
  }
}

_Layout.cshtml, including the Google authentication html:
<head>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</head>

<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="<CLIENT-ID>"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:5250"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

I think my Google settings are setup fine.

and

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Make sure that you are opening the consent screen on the default browser on the device
